# having trouble setting up NFS server on centos 6.5

Tags: linux, centos, nfs, linode

Setup:

1. Provider: Linode
2. nfs server: a linode with centos 6.5
3. nfs client: a linode with centos 6.5

When I tried mounting

```
mount.nfs: access denied by server while mounting x.x.x.x:/shared
```

This is happening when I try to start nfs service both on client and server

```
[shortfellow@li829-73 ~]$ sudo service nfs restart
Shutting down NFS daemon:                                  [  OK  ]
Shutting down NFS mountd:                                  [  OK  ]
Shutting down RPC idmapd:                                  [  OK  ]
FATAL: Module nfsd not found.
FATAL: Error running install command for nfsd
Starting NFS services:                                     [  OK  ]
Starting NFS mountd:                                       [  OK  ]
Starting NFS daemon:                                       [  OK  ]
Starting RPC idmapd:                                       [  OK  ]
```

I do not understand the problem.

Comment: What is the output of `uname -a`.

Answer (score 0):

Please post your kernel version with the output of `uname -a`.

Being that this is a Linode instance, you're probably running a special kernel managed by the provider. The errors you're seeing indicate that NFS is not compiled into the kernel or the module not available.

Can you try:

```
# modinfo nfsd
# modprobe nfsd
```

Comment: and when you get `modinfo: ERROR: Module nfsd not found`...?

Answer (score 0):

```
# /etc/init.d/nfs start
FATAL: Module nfsd not found.
FATAL: Error running install command for nfsd
```

...
It is actually harmless, you don't need to do anything. In case you want this to go away, uncomment (or add) the line

```
NFSD_MODULE="noload"
```

in `/etc/sysconfig/nfs` file.